# String.Format in C#

Tags: c#, string.format

I have an values like

```
1,000
25,000
500,000
```

Need to convert above values as like below without comma

```
1000
25000
500000
```

How to acheive this in C#?

how to get reverse output of this -

```
string.Format("{0:n}", 999999)
```

Comment: where do you get these values? are they in string or integer format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Replace` function of the string class like so:

```
string str = "25,000";
str = str.Replace(",", "");
```

EDIT:

As suggested by `Matthew Watson` from the comments

> If the string is returned from string.Format("{0:n}", 999999) run on a
>   machine in a locale that uses "." as the thousands separator, this
>   will fail

updated answer:

```
string num = "25,000";
NumberFormatInfo currentInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
num = num.Replace(currentInfo.NumberGroupSeparator, "");
```

Comment: 1+ for the simple solution but how you do this other way round

Comment: From the last line in the question, it appears that the OP already has a number in numeric data type

Comment: @Habib the last line in his question indicated that he wanted a reverse output of the string.Format function. He has the numbers in string.

Comment: @GianAcuna, you are right, since the OP has accepted the answer :) +1

Comment: @StephenL Note that if the string is returned from `string.Format("{0:n}", 999999)` run on a machine in a locale that uses `"."` as the thousands separator, this will fail. Should really use [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) for the current locale instead of hard-coding `","`.

Comment: @GianAcuna it would be great if you edited your answer as Matthew Watson recommended because someone else won't read these comments )

Comment: @GianAcuna now it is +1 :)