# Converting number to comma separated values

Tags: c#, string.format

I need to convert numbers into a comma separated format to display in `C#`.

For Example:

```
1000 to 1,000
45000 to 45,000
150000 to 1,50,000
21545000 to 2,15,45,000
```

How to achieve this in `C#`?

I tried the below code:

```cs
int number = 1000;
number.ToString("#,##0");
```

But it is not working for `lakhs`.

Comment: Did you try `ToString("N0");`

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number (`{0:#,#}` from this looks to be my favourite way if it works)

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.Format in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601968/string-format-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7):

I guess you can do this by creating a custom number format info for your needs

```
NumberFormatInfo nfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
// you are interested in this part of controlling the group sizes
nfo.CurrencyGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 };
nfo.CurrencySymbol = "";

Console.WriteLine(15000000.ToString("c0", nfo)); // prints 1,50,00,000
```

if specifically only for numbers then you could also do

```
nfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
nfo.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 };

Console.WriteLine(15000000.ToString("N0", nfo));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This saved the day

Comment: I m not getting decimals in this. How to get decimals like '10,200.15'

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar thread to yours [add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

and here's the solution that worked perfectly for me

```
     String.Format("{0:n}", 1234);

     String.Format("{0:n0}", 9876); // no decimals
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be unique and do extra work that you don't have to here is a function I created for integer numbers you can place commas at whatever interval you want, just put 3 for a comma for each thousandths or you could alternatively do 2 or 6 or whatever you like.

```
             public static string CommaInt(int Number,int Comma)
    {
     string IntegerNumber = Number.ToString();
     string output="";
     int q = IntegerNumber.Length % Comma;
     int x = q==0?Comma:q;
     int i = -1;
     foreach (char y in IntegerNumber)
     {
             i++;
             if (i == x) output += "," + y;
             else if (i > Comma && (i-x) % Comma == 0) output += "," + y;
             else output += y;

     }
     return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
ToString("#,##0.00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way:

```
Int32 number = 123456789;
String temp = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0:C0}", number);
//The above line will give Rs. 12,34,56,789. Remove the currency symbol
String indianFormatNumber = temp.Substring(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to pass a format into the **ToString()** method:

```
string format = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;Zero";
   decimal positiveMoney = 24508975.94m;
   decimal negativeMoney = -34.78m;
   decimal zeroMoney = 0m;
   positiveMoney.ToString(format);  //will return $24,508,975.94
   negativeMoney.ToString(format);  //will return -$34.78 
   zeroMoney.ToString(format);      //will return Zero
```

Hope this helps,